# CMake: run install step of ExternalProject_add target before build step of another target

Tags: cmake

My CMake build process brings in and builds another CMake-based project through `ExternalProject_add`. I need to run the INSTALL step for this target before the main project will build. However, I can't seem to specify the INSTALL step of my external project as a dependency for the build step of my main project. What would this target be called? Do INSTALL targets have names?

Comment: The easiest way is to make a second imported target that your main project depends on. [here's an example](https://github.com/nholthaus/units/blob/master/3rdParty/gtest/CMakeLists.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on OSX and Linux with `ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets(MYPROJECT install)`, although it doesn't seem to work on Windows. Will investigate further when I get a chance, but for now that's the answer I'm sticking with :S